# Replacing square brackets and quotations in SQL "in" statement from Python dictionary containing a list

Tags: python, sql

I'm trying to run some SQL in my Python script. One of the filters I want to use in the SQL "in" statement comes from a Python dictionary. One item in the dictionary can have multiple values from a list within the dictionary. I want to be able to pass the dictionary through the SQL "in" statement without it adding additional parentheses or brackets.

What I have:

```
code: 1      ###(or 2, or 3, or 4)
dictionary = {'1': 'Blue', '2': 'Red', '3': 'Green', '4': ['Blue','Red','Green']}

print("""select * from table a
where and a.color in (""" "{}".format(dictionary[code])+ """) ;""")
```

Issue:
For items in the dictionary that only have one key-pairing (1, 2, and 3), the insertion into the query works fine. For these, the result is:

```
select * from table a where a.color in ('Blue')
select * from table a where a.color in ('Red')       
select * from table a where a.color in ('Green')
```

When I try to reference the list in the dictionary, I get back a string with both square brackets and single quotations, like:

```
select * from table a where a.color in ('['Blue', 'Red', 'Green']')
```

I need to remove the single quotations and brackets at the end so that my query can run properly.
How can I do this? I apologize, I am quite new learning this.

Comment: why not use proper argument formatting? which database package are you using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Anis R. mentioned; you need to join the list, but only if it is a list.

Here is a complete working example :)

```
#code = 2     ###(or 2, or 3, or 4)
dictionary = {'1': 'Blue', '2': 'Red', '3': 'Green', '4': ['Blue','Red','Green']}

def get_sql(code):
    lbl = ''

    # print(type(dictionary[str(code)]))

    if type(dictionary[str(code)]) == str:
        lbl = dictionary[str(code)]
    else:
        lbl = "', '".join(dictionary[str(code)])

    return ("select * from table a where and a.color in ('" + lbl + "') ;")

print(get_sql(2))
print(get_sql(4))
```

Produces

```
select * from table a where and a.color in ('Red') ;
select * from table a where and a.color in ('Blue', 'Red', 'Green') ;
```

Comment: Looks like it would work, but vulnerable to SQL injection. Worth a mention in case those colors are coming from user input.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of a list, you can use Python's `join` method, e.g. using

```
', '.join(['Blue','Red','Green']) # returns 'Blue, Red, Green'
```

Quite close to what we want! We just need to adjust this a little bit to add quotation marks around each string. To do so:

```
'"' + '", "'.join(['Blue','Red','Green']) + '"'  #returns '"Blue", "Red", "Green"'
```

---

Also, to check whether an element `x` is a list, you can check `if isinstance(x, list):`.